# Arp reply on behalf of another devices on Linux

Tags: arp

There are devices on a network that don't support ARP (let's name them NARPs) and a device that supports ARP, running Linux (lets' name it LX). LX knows the IP and MAC addresses of NARPs. What is required to make a LX respond on ARP requests instead of NARPs? I've read about Proxy ARP, but this is not exactly what I need. Proxy ARP will respond with its own MAC address and then forward all the packets to the real destination, but I want the LX to respond with the MAC addresses of NARPs so that traffic goes directly to them.

Comment: What kind of device can communicate with TCP/IP but leaves one of the most crucial and fundamental and simple protocols unimplemented?

Comment: Its a microchip used in IP-PBX. Several of those are managed by a single controller. Till now the voice streams were sent to the controller (LX) that forwarded them to the devices, so ARP was not required (controller knows the MAC addresses). Now we want the remote side to send the streams directly to the devices, but ARP functionality is missing.